# How to create base 64 Data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, base64, nsdata

I'm trying to create base64 data for protobuf encoding library.
I found this code:

```
/* Create a Base-64, UTF-8 encoded NSData from the receiver's contents using the given options.
*/
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
func base64EncodedDataWithOptions(options: NSDataBase64EncodingOptions) -> NSData
```

In the source code of NSData. As I got, this method have to return base64encoded NSDate.

But I can't understand, how to convert my NSData(which I'm receiving from API) to this Base64 NSDate.

Comment: Instead of just looking for code look at the Apple documentation. A took like [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash) can help you find needed methods in the Apple documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said your data is `NSData`. Then just call the `base64EncodedDataWithOptions` and assign it to a new variable/constant:

```
let newData = yourData.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.allZeros)
```

Check NSDataBase64EncodingOptions for encoding options and change allZeros as appropriate.